# proving Big-O runtime of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to learn how to prove Big O correctly.

what i am trying to do is find some C and N0 for a given function.

the definition given for Big-O is

> Let f(n) and g(n) be functions mapping nonnegative integers to real numbers.
> We say that f(n) is O(g(n)) if there is a real constant c > 0 and an integer
> constant n0 ≥ 1 such that for all n ≥ n0, f(n) ≤ c g(n).

Given the polynomial (n+1)^5 i need to show that it has a runtime of O(n^5).

my question is, how do i find such c and N0 from the definition above, and how do i continue my algebra to see if it runs n^5?

So far by trying induction i have,

> (n+1)^5 = n^5 + 5n^4 + n^3 + 10n^2 + 5n^1 + n^0

find the n+1 element so

> n^5 + 5n^4 + n^3 + 10n^2 + 5n^1 + n^0 <= n^5 + 5n^5 + n^5 + 10n^5 + 5n^5 + n^5
>
> n^5 + 5n^4 + 10n^2 + 5n + 1  <= 22n^5

Answer (score 1):

You want a constant *c* such that *(n + 1) <sup>5</sup> ≤ c n <sup>5</sup>*. For that, you do not need induction, only a bit of algebra and it turns out you actually already found such a *c*, but missed the n<sub>0</sub> in the process. So let's start from the beginning.

Note that *c* does not need to be tight, it can be way bigger than necessary and will still prove time-complexity. We will use that to our advantage.

We can first develop the left side as you did.

> *(n + 1) <sup>5</sup> = n<sup>5</sup> + 5n<sup>4</sup> + 10n<sup>3</sup> + 10 n<sup>2</sup> + 5n + 1*

**For *n ≥ 1***, we have that *n, n<sup>2</sup>, n<sup>3</sup>, n<sup>4</sup> ≤ n<sup>5</sup>*, an thus.

> *(n + 1) <sup>5</sup> ≤ (1 + 5 + 10 + 10 + 5 + 1) n<sup>5</sup> = 22n<sup>5</sup>*

And there you got a *c* such that *(n + 1) <sup>5</sup> ≤ c n<sup>5</sup>*. That *c* is *22*.

And since we stated above that this holds if *n ≥ 1*, then we have that *n<sub>0</sub> = 1*.

### Generalization

This generalizes for any degree. In general given the polynomial *f(n) = (n + a)<sup>b</sup>*, then you know that there exists a number *c* that is found by summing all the coefficients of the polynomial after development. It turns out the exact value of *c* does not matter so you do not need to compute it, all that matter is that we proved its existence and thus *(n + a)<sup>b</sup>* is *O(n<sup>b</sup>)*.